# How to validate the Dateformat Mask using ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, date-format, coldfusion-9

How to check the date format using ColdFusion. I want to check that the user enters a date in the format `yyyy-mm-dd`. When a user enters a date in the format `dd-mm-yyyy` I want to show an error message. Is there any simple way to solve this?

Comment: How are they entering the date and how are you verifying (just server side or client side too)? You will probably have to verify the first 4 characters are numeric.

Comment: You can accept date in any format, validated on client side, and the can convert it to desired format while processing on the server.

Comment: Are you asking how to ensure the user enters the date in the required format, or are you asking how to manage dates that might be entered in several different formats?

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce I am asking first one. How to ensure the user enters the date in the required format?

Comment: I've tried to clarify your question. Please do [edit] it if it's still not quite right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you need to validate the date format from the server side?
Here I've given a simple RegEx check to check the format and did some checks to validate.

```
<cfset regex = '[0-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]'>
<cfset myDate = '2006-12-39'>
<cfset MatchedDate = REMatchNoCase(regex, myDate)>
<cfif arrayLen(MatchedDate) AND isDate(myDate) AND MatchedDate[1] EQ myDate>
    Valid date
<cfelse>
    Invalid date
</cfif>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes. I need to validate the dateformat on server side.

Answer (score 4):

As I said in comment, you can validate it on client side with following function

```
function validateDate(){

var dt = document.forms["Form_Name"]["Date_Field"].value;
var pattern =/^([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{1,2})$/;
if (dt == null || dt == "" || !pattern.test(dt))
{
    alert("invalid date");
    return false;
}
else{
    return true
}
```

}

then in cf code, while processing

```
<cfset desiredFormat=DateFormat(form.Date_Field,"yyyy-mm-dd")>
```

ps: the js function was taken from [Javascript Date Validation ( DD/MM/YYYY) & Age Checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820257/javascript-date-validation-dd-mm-yyyy-age-checking)

Comment: Thanks. Is this Solve server side validation too? Need to do the server side validation.

Comment: On server, you can check with isDate(form.Date_Field) whether this is valid date or not and then can convert into your desired format with DateFormat function.

Comment: Be careful with using isDate().  ColdFusion is pretty generous about what it considers a valid date.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
<cfinput name="StartDate" 
validate="date" 
type="text" 
maxlength="10" 
mask="9999-99-99"
message="Start Date must be a valid date." 
required="yes">
```

The key is the mask attribute.  However, if you pre-populate this field, attempting to change the value can become frustrating.

Comment: I would recommend the [jquery masked input plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) before using `cfinput`.  stay away from the CFUI stuff.