# Check dateformat with regex in JS

Tags: javascript, regex, date, datetime

My question is simple but takes work. I tried lots of regex expressions to check my datetime is ok or not, but though I am sure my regex exprerssion is correct it always return to me isnotok with ALERT. Can you check my code?

```
validateForLongDateTime('22-03-1981')



function validateForLongDateTime(date){
    var regex=new RegExp("/^\d{2}[.-/]\d{2}[.-/]\d{4}$/");
    var dateOk=regex.test(date);
    if(dateOk){
      alert('ok');

    }else{
        alert('notok');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least 2 issues with the regex:

- It has unescaped forward slashes
- The hyphen in the character classes is unescaped and forms a range (matching only `.` and `/`) that is not what is necessary here.

[image]

The "fixed" regex will look like:

```
/^\d{2}[.\/-]\d{2}[.\/-]\d{4}$/
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/uD7jF2/2)

However, you cannot validate dates with it since it will also match `37-67-5734`.

- Here is [an SO post with a comprehensive regex approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15504877/3832970) that looks viable

Here is [my enahanced version](https://regex101.com/r/nP3qU2/2) with a character class for the delimiter:

```
^(?:(?:31([\/.-])(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)([\/.-])(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29([\/.-])0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])([\/.-])(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$
```

- Here is [an SO post showing another approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19820503/3832970) using [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Example:_Using_parse)

Answer (score 0):

this way you can validate date between 1 to 31 and month 1 to 12

```
var regex = /^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](19|20)\d\d$/
```

see this demo here https://regex101.com/r/xP1bD2/1